# How to updates docker container blkio configuration dynamically?

Tags: docker, cgroups

I can run `docker run` with `--blkio-weight` `--blkio-weight-device` `--device-read-bps` `--device-read-iops` `--device-write-bps` `--device-write-iops`.

The `docker update` command can dynamically updates container configuration.

However, I can just update the `--blkio-weight` arg.

Why does `docker update` not support other args like `--blkio-weight-device`?

Is there a way to do that, like modifying cgroups args manually?

update:
I tried to edit cgroups args in `/sys/fs/cgroup/blkio/.../blkio.throttle.write_bps_device` manually and it works. It seems that the blkio args can be modified dynamically.

Comment: I guess this cannot be changed at runtime, but can only be set when at the time a process is started.

Answer (score 1):

Because this is the only flag that `docker update` command support.

```
--blkio-weight      Block IO (relative weight), between 10 and 1000, or 0 to disable (default 0)
```

> The docker update command dynamically updates container configuration.
>   You can use this command to prevent containers from consuming too many
>   resources from their Docker host. With a single command, you can place
>   limits on a single container or on many. To specify more than one
>   container, provide space-separated list of container names or IDs.

These are the supported flag.

```
--blkio-weight      Block IO (relative weight), between 10 and 1000, or 0 to disable (default 0)
--cpu-period        Limit CPU CFS (Completely Fair Scheduler) period
--cpu-quota     Limit CPU CFS (Completely Fair Scheduler) quota
--cpu-rt-period     API 1.25+
Limit the CPU real-time period in microseconds
--cpu-rt-runtime        API 1.25+
Limit the CPU real-time runtime in microseconds
--cpu-shares , -c       CPU shares (relative weight)
--cpus      API 1.29+
Number of CPUs
--cpuset-cpus       CPUs in which to allow execution (0-3, 0,1)
--cpuset-mems       MEMs in which to allow execution (0-3, 0,1)
--kernel-memory     Kernel memory limit
--memory , -m       Memory limit
--memory-reservation        Memory soft limit
--memory-swap       Swap limit equal to memory plus swap: ‘-1’ to enable unlimited swap
--pids-limit        API 1.40+
Tune container pids limit (set -1 for unlimited)
--restart       Restart policy to apply when a container exits
```

[docker-commandline-update](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/update/)